# buildroot opencv3 python package builds for the wrong target?

Tags: python, opencv, cmake, cross-compiling, buildroot

I am using buildroot tagged 2017.11.2 (building for aarch64). I enable build of python3 library for opencv3 in the buildroot configuration:

```
BR2_PACKAGE_PYTHON3=y
BR2_PACKAGE_OPENCV3=y
BR2_PACKAGE_OPENCV3_LIB_PYTHON=y
```

I can see during the build that cmake says:

```
--     Host:                        Linux 4.13.0-36-generic x86_64
--     Target:                      Linux aarch64
--     C++ Compiler:                /home/buildroot/output/host/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-g++  (ver 6.4.1)
```

But later I see

```
[100%] Linking CXX shared module ../../lib/python3/cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
[100%] Built target opencv_python3
```

I would expect `cv2.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so` to be named `cv2.cpython-36m-aarch64-linux-gnu.so`. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the required distutils environment variables are not set. Can you try setting `OPENCV3_CONF_ENV` to `$(PKG_PYTHON_DISTUTILS_ENV)`? If that works, please [prepare a patch](https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html#submitting-patches) and send it to [the Buildroot mailing list](http://lists.buildroot.org/mailman/listinfo/buildroot).

Comment: Thank you! This did help. I've [submitted patch](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/buildroot/2018-March/215246.html).

Comment: For reference: the patch is at http://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/882161/